# Utilizando o jsPDF, existem templates prontos?

Tags: javascript, template, pdf, jspdf

Estou utilizando o *jsPDF* para fazer um relatório a partir de alguns dados de entrada do usuário, porem estou tendo muitas dificuldades para deixar o relatório bonito ainda mais devido ao fato de que não sei personalizar muito com o *jsPDF*. Portanto existem *templates* prontos para essa ferramenta?

Alem disso ele tem suporte para gerar gráficos e colocar no relatório (PDF)?

[jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf)

[Documentação](https://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/doc/symbols/jsPDF.html)

Abaixo deixei como esta o meu código neste momento:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.setFontSize(22);
doc.text(40, 20, 'Relatorio - Departamento de Projetos');

doc.setFontSize(18);
doc.text(20, 40, 'Mes Anterior');

doc.setFontSize(12);
doc.text(20, 50, 'Data Inicio: ' + dtInicio1);
doc.text(100, 50, 'Data Fechamento: ' + dtFechamento1);
doc.text(20, 60, 'Projetos em Desenvolvimento: ' + pDesen1);
doc.text(20, 70, 'Projetos em Analise: ' + pAnalise1);
doc.text(20, 80, 'Projetos Cancelados: ' + pCancel1);

doc.setFontSize(18);
doc.text(20, 120, 'Mes Atual');

doc.setFontSize(12);
doc.text(20, 130, 'Data Inicio: ' + dtInicio2);
doc.text(100, 130, 'Data Fechamento: ' + dtFechamento2);
doc.text(20, 140, 'Projetos em Desenvolvimento: ' + pDesen2);
doc.text(20, 150, 'Projetos em Analise: ' + pAnalise2);
doc.text(20, 160, 'Projetos Cancelados: ' + pCancel2);

doc.save('Relatorio-DP.pdf');
```

Comment: Seja bem vindo. Acho que a pergunta ficaria ainda mais interessante se você criar um Snippet e postar o link da documentação do JsPDF.

Comment: Bom vou colocar o link da documentação, mas o que seria um Snippet?

Comment: Oficialmente não, mas já que ele aceita imagens e um pouco de HTML então talvez seja melhor procurar bibliotecas especificas como Fabric.js ou Raphal.js e pegar os graficos gerados exportar pra imagem e adicionar ao seu PDF.

Comment: Vlw pela dica, mas e no caso de templates ou modelos de pdf existe algum pronto para uso?

Answer (score 1):

Até onde eu sei, não existe templates protos, até porque nao é complicado de se criar, da para criar PDF a partir de um HTML (a resolução em geral fica ruim). 
Em caso de tabelas, voce pode usar o [Autotable](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable/), em seguida, segue um exemplo basico de formatação.

```
this.getDataUri('static/images/logo.gif', function(dataUri) {
          image = dataUri
      });

let doc = jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4')
            doc.setFont('Courier')
            // Titulo
            doc.setFontSize(20)
            doc.text('TEXTO', 215, 60)
            doc.line(40, 80, 550, 80)
            if(!this.data.Flag){
                doc.setFontSize(12)
                doc.text('Preview', 290, 75)
                doc.setFontSize(20)
            }

            // Logo
            doc.addImage(image, 30, 30)

            // Informação Cabeçalho
            doc.setFontSize(10)
            doc.text('TEXTO:', 50, 120)
            doc.text('TEXTO:', 50, 140)
            doc.text('TEXTO:', 50, 160)
            doc.text('Date:', 50, 180)
            doc.text('TEXTO:', 50, 200)
            doc.text('TEXTO:', 50, 280)

doc.save(this.data.title[0].title+'.pdf')
```

Lembrando que esse eé um exemplo bem basico, caso tenha dificuldade com um layout em especifico (que tenha em mente), poste seu codigo atual e o layout que pretende atingir que ajudamos.